# How to set a a particular datetime (Created or modified) in a document in Lotus Notes with C++?

Tags: c++, datetime, lotus-notes

I am Using Lotus notes 8.5. I am trying to create a new document in nsf database with a specific datetime using C++ API of Lotusnotes. But Document is created with Current Datetime.

Comment: Ken's answer is correct. If you're actually trying that and it's not working, then you're going to have to show us your code.

Comment: I am doing this.But its not working.I have already created the document and then create item.All other fields were created except date field. Here is my code for datetime field.                                                  LNDatetime dt;                                             LNDocument doc;                                dt.setdate(10,12,2012);                               dt.SetTime(12,30,10);                                     LNDatetimes dts;                                    dts.setValue(dt);  doc.CreateItem("$Created",&dts,LNITEMFLAGS_SUMMARY,LNITEMOPION_APPEND_ONLY);

Answer (score 1):

If you can set the $Created item on the document that should let you change the created date.

Comment: I am doing this.But its not working.I have already created the document and then create item.All other fields were created except date field. Here is my code for datetime field.                                                  LNDatetime dt;                                             LNDocument doc;                                dt.setdate(10,12,2012);                               dt.SetTime(12,30,10);                                     LNDatetimes dts;                                    dts.setValue(dt);  doc.CreateItem("$Created",&dts,LNITEMFLAGS_SUMMARY,LNITEMOPION_APPEND_ONLY);

Comment: Perhaps the last flag needs to be LNITEMOPTION_DELETE_APPEND?  The $Created item should be there when you create the document.

Comment: I have done by using flag LNITEMOPTION_DELETE_APPEND. but the date time i have set is not visible in summary view.

Answer (score 0):

Code with the Notes C++ API really should never ignore the LNSTATUS return that comes back from the calls.  As you say that the item is not being created, the LNSTATUS would be the first place I'd look for a reason.

Also, it doesn't make sense (to me, anyhow) to have $Created be a timedate range, but your code is passing an LNDatetimes object.  I suspect that you should be a passing a single LNDatetime instead.

Comment: the LNSTATUS return succesful. But the datetime that i have set is not visible in summary view. and if u r talking about using LNdatetime instead of using LNDatetimes.i would like to tell u that function CREATITEM() does not take LNDatetime argument as an item.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that CreateItem does not take LNDatetime as the newitem argument in that calling sequence. It only takes classes derived from LNItem. But I believe that if you use this signature:  LNSTATUS CreateItem( const LNString &name, LNITEMTYPE type, void *data, LNINT datalen, LNITEMFLAGS flags=LNITEMFLAGS_AUTO_SUMMARY, LNITEMOPTION option=LNITEMOPTION_APPEND_ONLY, LNItem *newitem=0) const; then you can pass LNDatetime as the data arg. Still, that seems to likely be equivalent to what you are already doing, so I don't know if it could help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "not visible in the summary view".  Are you using NotesPeek to look at the resulting note data?

Comment: No i m nt using NotesPeek. Actually i m creating a new database & add a new document to it for that i m copying only view from a sample database by using DBoptions.SetCopyDesignOnly(TRUE) & then i add items like subject, sender,datetime,recepient,etc. to the document and then save the document.when i open the database in lotus notes then i see that document shows all the fields(send to,subject,attachment check,size) in summary view except the datetime value that i had set.It shows the current datetime in summary view of that document that i have created instead of the datetime that i have set.

Comment: You might try saving the document first and then changing the date and saving the document again. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!  One thing you may not have realized is you only need to comment in one place, whichever makes more sense for the comment. B

Comment: I strongly suggest that you download a copy of NotesPeek and use it to examine the document and see what is in the $Created item, what data type it is, etc.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz : Doc.CreateItem("$Created",datetxt,LNITENFLAGSUMMARY,LNITEMOPTION_APPEND_ONLY); here datetxt is txt value of LNdatetime. When i am doing this ,den the value of created item is visible in NOtesPeek. But the value is not visible in notes database in summary view when i open the database file in lotusnotes. In lotus notes, summary view shows current datetime instead of datetime that i have set.

Comment: What is the formula in the column of the view?  We've been assuming that it is @Created, but you've never actually told us what it is.